# move_uploaded_file function not working in godaddy?

Tags: php

i am currently having a problem and i have tried searching a lot on this topic but i still can't find an answer on why move_uploaded_file is not working, i am able to create directory using mkdir() but move file doesn't seem to work, i have also tried creating custom php.ini file with file_uploads=on in it but still nothing happens and even my directory created in also having 0755 or 755 write and read permissions.

I have tried adding delimiter as in below and just about everything but still nothing happens, I really need to move my uploaded and help would appreciated.

Here is my code :

```
<?php
  //Profile Image upload script
  if (isset($_FILES['profilepic'])) {
   if (((@$_FILES["profilepic"]["type"]=="image/jpeg") || (@$_FILES["profilepic"]["type"]=="image/png") || (@$_FILES["profilepic"]["type"]=="image/gif"))&&(@$_FILES["profilepic"]["size"] < 1048576)) //1 Megabyte
  {
   $chars = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789";
   $rand_dir_name = substr(str_shuffle($chars), 0, 15);
   $dir = "./userdata/profile_pics/$rand_dir_name";
   mkdir($dir);
   if(is_dir($dir . "/" .$_FILES["profile‌​pic"]["name"])) {
   echo "sdsadsad";
   }
   move_uploaded_file($_FILES["profilepic"]["tmp_name"], $dir . "/" .$_FILES["profile‌​pic"]["name"]);
    $profile_pic_name = $_FILES["profilepic"]["tmp_name"];
    echo $profile_pic_name;
    $profile_pic_query = mysqli_query($conn,"UPDATE users2 SET profile_pic='$rand_dir_name/$profile_pic_name' WHERE username='$user'");

  }
  else
  {
      $msg5 =  "Invailid File! Your image must be no larger than 1MB and it must be either a .jpg, .jpeg, .png or .gif";
  }
  }

?>
```

and here is form :

```
<form action="" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input type="file" name="profilepic" /><br><br>
<input type="submit" name="uploadpic" value="Change Profile Photo">
</form>
```

Comment: try with->mkdir($dir, 0777, true);

Answer (score 1):

```
Try this

$old_umask = umask(0);
mkdir($dir, 0777);
umask($old_umask);
```

Comment: nope, it still doesn't move the file there but directory is mode with all the file permissions

Answer (score 1):

Try maybe one of these these

```
    <?php 
    // Read and write for owner, nothing for everybody else
    chmod("/somedir/somefile", 0600); 
    // Read and write for owner, read for everybody else
    chmod("/somedir/somefile", 0644);
    ?>
```

before moving it anywhere

Comment: i'll work on that later but moving is not working yet!!